# function dmetaphone(text) does not exist and fuzzystrmatch extension is already there

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

During migration I'm getting erorr dmetaphone not exists and i have check there is already fuzzystrmatch extension is present, what could be cause of this error ?

```
class AddPgSearchDmetaphoneSupportFunctions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    say_with_time("Adding support functions for pg_search :dmetaphone") do
      execute <<-'SQL'
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_search_dmetaphone n(text) RETURNS text LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE STRICT AS $function$
  SELECT array_to_string(ARRAY(SELECT dmetaphone(unnest(regexp_split_to_array($1, E'\\s+')))), ' ')
$function$;
      SQL
    end
  end

  def self.down
    say_with_time("Dropping support functions for pg_search :dmetaphone") do
      execute <<-'SQL'
DROP FUNCTION pg_search_dmetaphone(text);
      SQL
    end
  end
end
```

Here are error log.

```
== 20170324124420 AddPgSearchDmetaphoneSupportFunctions: migrating ============
-- Adding support functions for pg_search :dmetaphone
-- execute("CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_search_dmetaphone(text) RETURNS text LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE STRICT AS $function$\n  SELECT array_to_string(ARRAY(SELECT dmetaphone(unnest(regexp_split_to_array($1, E'\\\\s+')))), ' ')\n$function$;\n")
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function dmetaphone(text) does not exist
LINE 2:   SELECT array_to_string(ARRAY(SELECT dmetaphone(unnest(rege...
                                              ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_search_dmetaphone(text) RETURNS text LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE STRICT AS $function$
  SELECT array_to_string(ARRAY(SELECT dmetaphone(unnest(regexp_split_to_array($1, E'\\s+')))), ' ')
```

Here are psql logs for fuzzystrmatch.

```
db_dev=# create extension fuzzystrmatch;
ERROR:  function "levenshtein" already exists with same argument types
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have a function `levenshtein` in the same schema where you want to create the extension.

Simple solutions:

- Drop the function before you create the extension.
- Create the extension in some other schema.

Odds are that the function is a leftover from a version of `fuzzystrmatch` that has been installed in a pre-9.0 PostgreSQL database by script and just been upgraded ever since.

Normally that would enable you to run

```
CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch FROM unpackaged;
```

But since the function `dmetaphone` doesn't see to exist, that is not an option.

Comment: dmetaphone was added in 1.1.  So doing the `CREATE...FROM unpackaged` first to get 1.0 followed up `ALTER EXTENSION ... UPDATE` to get 1.1 should work.